# How to change drive in Netrw and how to stay in givm window but quit Netrw?

Tags: vim

As a newbie in `vim` I am full of silly questions. :D

Running `gvim` on `Windows 7` 64bit, I am careful to avoid complex plugins but try to start from whatever existing to be familiar with the tool.

So now I cannot find a way to lookup files on `D` drive, how to switch in `Netrw`? Do I have to mount it like in Linux?

Also, how to quit `Netrw` but still stay in `gvim`?

Last question, is `nerdtree` really much better than `netrw`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### A way to lookup files on D drive

The plugin is triggered by `:edit`ing a *directory*, so this is what you'll do:

```
:edit D:\
```

You could also `:cd D:\` first, and then `:edit .`, or use the dedicated `:Ex`, `:Sex`, etc. command(s) that the plugin provides.

#### How to quit Netrw but still stay in gvim

In Vim, everything is a *buffer* displayed in a *window*. Unlike in IDEs, plugins have to "fake" their user interface as special buffers. So, you leave the netrw buffer like any other: Start `:edit file`, or `:enew` for a new one, or `:bdelete`, or `:bnext`, or ...

#### Is nerdtree really much better than netrw

The main differentiator is that NERDTree defaults to a hierarchical file listing in a left-hand sidebar (similar to Windows Explorer). You can have that in netrw, too (`let g:netrw_liststyle = 3`). There's feature parity in other areas, too (e.g. bookmarks), while some things are unique to NERDTree (fancier tree visualization, customizable action menu). netrw provides transparent access to remote file systems, which NERDTree doesn't. You can even use both in parallel!

I'd recommend to read NERDTree's help, and once you run into something that netrw doesn't do well, remember NERDTree and put it to the test.

Comment: Thanks! very thorough explanation ! one question: `let g:netrw_liststyle = 3` list file in tree hierarchy but may not necessary on the left side? if so then how to arrange the window always on the `left` or `top`?

Comment: `:Vex` does that (on the left).

Comment: For saving keystrokes, it appears the trailing slash is unnecessary. For example: `:e d:` works to switch to the D:\ drive.

Comment: Starting with netrw v150, :Lexplore will put a netrw browser on the left hand side.  With v153, :Lexplore! is available and will put a netrw browser on the right hand side.  Netrw is now up to v153i; you can get it from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW .

Answer (score 1):

The command `:Ex D:` should show you a listing of drive D:. Just press <kbd>:</kbd>, type `Ex D:`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`:q` or `:close` should close any window or tab, including netrw.

You may wish to review the [netrw documentation.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075)

Comment: thanks. It just if there is only `netrw` in the window, so `:q` may quit `gvim`? How can I stay in `gvim` but leave `netrw` in this case?